# How to get initial state of bluetooth on application startup (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

Currently I monitor Bluetooth status like this:

```
class One: NSObject {
    private let centralManager = CBCentralManager()

    init( ) {
        super.init()
        centralManager.delegate = self
    }
}
extension One: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: .xxx, 
            object: central.state)
    }
}
```

And then another class listens to this notification, etc. Code above is simplified, as I think everything else is irrelevant, but let me know if something is missing from this picture.

This code works if bluetooth status is changed while application is running. But when application starts I am not getting any notification, so I don't know what is initial status of the Bluetooth.

So how do I get initial status of bluetooth on application startup?

Comment: Probably your initial notification is firing before your other objects have registered as observers. You can check your `CBCentralManager`'s `state` at any time.  You should provide a method in class `One` that allows any other objects that need to know the state to query it when they start rather than having them wait for a notification.

Comment: @Paulw11 (although it's a while now), but your hint was exactly what was happening. If you convert it to answer, I will accept it.